# elasticsearch copy_to as text property

Tags: elasticsearch

I have several properties that I want to combine in one field.

```
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "transform": {
                "script": "ctx._source['combined'] = ctx._source['prop1'] + ' ' + ctx._source['prop2.prop2internal'] + ' ' + ctx._source['prop3']"
            },
            "properties": {
                "prop1": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "copy_to" : "combined"
                },
                "prop2": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties" : {
                        "prop2internal" : {
                            "type" : "text",
                            "copy_to" : "combined"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "prop3": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "copy_to" : "combined"
                },
                "combined"  : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "store" : "yes"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

POST:

```
POST /my_index/my_type 
{
    "prop1": 'w A',
    "prop2": [prop2internal : 'x B'],
    "prop3": ['y C', 'z D']
}
```

Now my combined field has ['w A', 'x B', 'y C', 'z D']. I wish to search for any combination of values in it. For example: 'w z C' must match.
I tried to script these props as a concatenated string, but my script is throwing an error

```
 reason: 'Failed to parse mapping [my_type]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:
```

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: 5.1.1. with lucene 6.3.0

Comment: The `transform` feature has been [removed in ES 5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_source_transform_removed) you should use the [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-apis.html) instead if you need to transform your source before indexing it.